# Wordpress Plugin Ajax Don't execute function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying execute ajax call in wordpress but not execute code in function php.

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $("#formato").change(function(){
        var formato_rassegna = $("#formato").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : my_vars.ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'filtroformato',
                tipologia : formato_rassegna
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                console.log(formato_rassegna);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Plugin.php

```
    function adminprintdoc_stylescriptelement_init() {
        wp_enqueue_style('adprdocasweome-style','https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('adprdochover-style', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/rassegnastampa/css/animation.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('adprdoc-style', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/rassegnastampa/css/rassegnastampa.css');

        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/rassegnastampa/js/rassegnastampa.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'my-custom', 'my_vars', array(
            'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
        }
    add_action('init', 'adminprintdoc_stylescriptelement_init');
}

function filtroformato() {
    echo "ciaoooooo";
    die();// chiudo l'esecuzione della chiamata AJAX, evitando di far ritornare errori da parte di WordPress
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filtroformato', 'filtroformato' );
```

Classe.php

```
 <form>
                <div><p>Formato:</p><select name="formato" id="formato">
                        <option>indifferente</option><option>cartaceo</option><option>web</option><option>social</option>
                    </select></div>
                <div>
</form>
```

The function javascript work good but not execute code inside the php function filtroformato() ... Why?

Comment: add `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filtroformato', 'filtroformato' );` then check browser console log for any errors

Comment: Nothig is change :-(

Comment: show browser console log

Comment: console log print name of vaue of formato div . Nothing error is printed

Comment: `success : function( response ) {
                console.log(response);
            }`

Comment: Thank you so much. all work good. Thank you